# Equivalent of a one-tailed paired t-test for circular data?

Tags: paired-data, circular-statistics

I have a set of paired circular measurements representing the timing (in phase) of two different events. I would like to determine whether one event occurs earlier (smallest difference in a counter-clockwise direction) or later (smallest difference in a clockwise direction) in phase than the other, or if they are at the same time (difference = 0).  So, if my data series are A and B, I would like to test that

$$A_i - B_i \neq 0\text{.}$$
and determine the direction of the smallest difference.

It looks like I might be able to use a Rayleigh test to check whether $A_i - B_i \neq 0$, but that doesn't exactly get at what I want.

Edited to add: One thing I have tried is calculating the circular difference of
$A - B$, and calculating 95% confidence intervals of the mean of that difference, with the logic being that if the confidence intervals exclude 0 degrees, there is a difference in timing. I do not know if that is an acceptable approach.

Comment: The p-value from a t-test does not give the probability that the means differ. Is that exactly what you want to be able to say, something like a $70\%$ or $99\%$ chance that the mean of $A$ is greater than the mean of $B$?

Comment: @Dave That is more than what I want. In the simplest case, I would like to test the alternative hypothesis that the mean of A is greater than the mean of B.

Comment: Please explain to us what "$\lt$" might mean for circular data.

Comment: @whuber That's a fair point. I suppose what I'm trying to get at is whether event B occurs more closely to A in the counterclockwise(earlier) or clockwise(later) direction, or if they are at the same time. Does that make more sense?

Comment: That helps.  Please note that "$A_i - B_i \ne 0$" is not a valid hypothesis: it's a statement about the *data.* This does not appear to be a classical hypothesis test because it partitions the possible states of nature into *three,* not two, disjoint groups: the underlying circular means are either equal, or the first is earlier than the second, or the second is earlier than the first. This suggests a need to explore your loss function and that comes down to you telling us how you intend to use the results of this analysis and what the consequences of errors might be.

Comment: @whuber I see. So, these are data on the timing of tongue movements during the chewing cycle of macaques. We're interested in what aspects of tongue movement happen at which point during the cycle (e.g. does tongue flexion happen before tongue rotation). Ultimately this may inform knowledge of human chewing and rehab, but I'd say the consequences of errors are very low.

Comment: Testing might not be appropriate.  Instead, wouldn't you want to *characterize* or *measure* or *explore* those aspects of tongue movement?

Comment: We've already done a lot of that-- measuring the movement, characterizing the movement in three dimensions over time, summarizing it over multiple chews. I really just want to show that how the peaks in one movement vary relative to the peaks in another movement. It's difficult to show without looking at the events in a paired fashion, because the summaries of the cycles mask that variation. But when you do a pairwise comparison, like the one I tried, there do appear to be consistent differences in timing. I just want to do this correctly.

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.